# Custom Attribute class not getting called?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, attributes

I created an attribute class, here is the code

```
    namespace ZDemo.Validate1
{
    public class ValidateRequest : ActionFilterAttribute
    {

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
           /*further code*/
            }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

}

And added it as an attribute to some actions in different controllers

```
  [Validate1.ValidateRequest]
    public ActionResult Add()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

But when I run this code with a debugger it is not being called at all.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like there are copy/paste errors in your code? You show `base.OnActionExecuting` outside of the `OnActionExecuting` method. That wouldn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

Call `base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);` at the beginning of the method:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

    //Your code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, would be nice if you also provide the reason?